# Tomcat Server to test SOAP service NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, apache-axis, soap-client, tomcat8

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.isChildFirstClassLoading()Z
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.deployServicesInWARClassPath(JAXWSDeployer.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.init(JAXWSDeployer.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.initializeDeployers(DeploymentEngine.java:989)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.setConfigContext(DeploymentEngine.java:981)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.setConfigContext(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:350)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 14, 2017 4:49:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [AxisAdminServlet] in web application [/ASDAReceiptData] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.isChildFirstClassLoading()Z
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.deployServicesInWARClassPath(JAXWSDeployer.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.init(JAXWSDeployer.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.initializeDeployers(DeploymentEngine.java:989)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.setConfigContext(DeploymentEngine.java:981)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.setConfigContext(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:350)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isChildFirstClassLoading()` has been introduced since Axis2 version 1.5.5. So you may have to upgrade Axis to 1.5.5 or later.